# Sharing a file between multiple locations

Tags: windows, unix, mercurial

We are currently using Subversion (on Windows) for our source control but we examine switching to Mercurial. One problem is that we use externals in our repositories to share single files between multiple sub-projects. If one version of such a file is edited, the changes are propagated to each other version in our check-out. Is there a way to achieve the same in Mercurial, i.e. the same file in multiple locations? On Unix, this may be possible using some kind of links. But how about Windows?

Comment: why not create a commons repo for storing those files? In Windows you have to put them in some common location, and configure the sub-projects to access that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mercurial has the [Subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) features which is a little bit like svn externals.

The Mercurial feature is a more complicated than external in  my point of view, but you can achieve the same goal with it and it is more flexible.

You can even use Subversion or Git repository as subrepo in Mercurial, so depending on what you're doing now, you could reuse your actual externals repo without any changes.

Everything is well explained in the linked documentation to have a good start with this functionnality !

BTW, symbolic links also exists on Windows : [NTFS Symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read about the subrepository feature, but unfortunately, it only seems to work for folders and not for single files. And our project structure is too complex to put together all the files that may be shared in different locations. But the subrepo feature may at least come in handy for handling some of our dependencies.

I didn't know about NTFS symlinks (only about junctions). If Mercurial could handle them, I suppose this would solve this particular problem.

Comment: @fschoenm AFAIK, Mercurial handles NTFS symlinks.

Comment: I tried NTFS symlinks (and hardlinks) but Mercurial didn't seem to support either. Instead I only got copies instead of links when I did a clone of my original reposity.

Comment: Correct, Mercurial does not support NTFS symlinks. See [Issue1825](http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue1825).